# Choregraphe Switch between Apps with NAO

Tags: python, nao-robot, choregraphe, naos-project

I have created several apps for NAO in Choregraphe and would like to be able to launch them though a single 'Master' application.

Through Master's dialog box I call `^switchFocus(traffic_lights-7xxxx/behavior_1)` and it works fine. It stops Master app and Launches TrafficLights app.

**Is there a way to switch back to the Master app once the second app is stopped?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [an alternate overload for switching focus](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/interaction/autonomouslife-api.html#ALAutonomousLifeProxy::switchFocus__ssCR.iCR) that supports exactly that. In Python, you could write:

```py
life = self.session().service("ALAutonoumousLife")
life.switchFocus("traffic_lights-7xxxx/behavior_1", 1)
```

In QiChat, you can theoretically perform [this kind of calls](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-naoqi-25/naoqi-developer-guide/naoqi-apis/naoqi-interaction-engines/aldialog/qichat-table-0#-pcall-). Therefore this should work:

```
^pCall(ALAutonomousLife(traffic_lights-7xxxx/behavior_1, 1))
```

Comment: Hey Victor, thanks for your reply. I had already tried the [overload alternative](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/interaction/autonomouslife-api.html#ALAutonomousLifeProxy::switchFocus__ssCR.iCR) but it didn't work. What **DID** work though was `^pCall(ALAutonomousLife.switchFocus(traffic_lights-xxxx/behavior_1, 1))` . It launches the second app and when the second app is finished it launches the first app again. Thank you Victor